# How can I make two models the same "type"?

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models. Rhyme, CommunityRhyme, and AssortedRhymes.

Rhyme(s) are collected by a bot.

CommunityRhyme(s) are rhymes added by the community.

AssortedRhymes contains a ManyToManyField that references only the Rhyme model.

How can I make it so that Rhyme and CommunityRhyme are of the same "type" so that the AssortedRhymes ManyToManyField that references the Rhyme model can also reference (add) CommunityRhymes?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the CommunityRhyme model and added a "is_community" Boolean field to Rhyme.